# Angular2 Event Emitter from parent to child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have question about Event Emitter in Angular2. This is really nice feature, but I wonder, that can I use it not from child to parent, but from parent to child.

In model child-> parent We declare some emitter  in child component, and emit point, in html we set `(emitter)="parentFunc($event)"`.

How we can do it in model parent child? it is possible? If not, shoud I use ViewChild instead?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses unidirectional data flow and gained huge performance benefits from that.

From parent to child you can use property binding

To pass data from child to parent events are used `@Output()`.

Therefore there is a distinct mechanism for each direction and there shouldn't be any need to use `@Output()` from parent to child.

Comment: Hi, How do I communicate between child components using EventEmitter?

Comment: What do you mean with "between child components". `@Output()` are for communication from child to parent. Perhaps you mean `<child1 #child1></child1><child2 (outputOfChild2)="child1.someMethodOnChild1($event)"></child2>`

Comment: Communication between Two siblings under parent component

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error "cannot read property "onUpdate" of undefined."onUpdate is my method on child1

Comment: I used a messaging service of eventemitters for communication between any components in a module. worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. The Angular2 team discourages using ´EventEmitter` for anything else than `@Output()`s. Use `Subject` instead, it's currently the same but `EventEmitter` semantics are prone to future change.